# What is the best way to check that a url namespace is unique?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to generate a unique namespace ("7FH98T") for my "Page" web pages . At first I was thinking about generating a namespace then querying the database to check that the namespace does not exist but I'm thinking if there are 500'000 pages then querying all namespaces every time a new page is made will not be very efficient.

I realise I can just run db.session.commit() and if there is an exception just rollback and generate a new namespace but I would rather handle checking uniqueness within the generate_namespace() function.

Here is my code. I hope I explained what I am trying to do clearly. Thanks in advance.

```
class Page(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pages'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    namespace = db.Column(db.String(6), unique=True)

    @staticmethod
    def generate_namespace():
        import random
        import string

        while unique == False:
            namespace = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(6))
            p = Page.query.filter_by(namespace=namespace).first()
            if not p:  # Is this really the best way to do this?
                continue
            else:
                unique = True

        return namespace
```

Comment: At least per your comment in the code, that is the best way to do that.

Comment: As far as repeatedly querying (although the chances that you'd have to query more than once per page are astronomical), create a `hash` or `btree` index on the namespace column.

Answer (score 1):

[If you need a unique identifier then one solution is to generate a UUID](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/uuid.html#module-uuid)

```
import uuid

class Page(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pages'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    namespace = db.Column(db.String(6), unique=True)

    @staticmethod
    def generate_namespace():
        namespace = uuid.uuid4() # Will produce a unique to the world identifier.
        return namespace
```

Also, I highly suggest that you keep imports at the top of your module. Imports take a loooong time.